# when I use 'for xml path' syntax, I face ((No column name was specified for column 1 of 'x')) error

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my code:

```
with resultMsg_reportCard
(
   select aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
   from tbl_something

   union

   select aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
   from tbl_somethingElse
)   

insert aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
select aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
from
(
   select rm_rc.aa,rm_rc.bb,rm_rc.cc,rm_rc.dd,a.ee
     N'something'+gg.title
     char(13)+char(10)
     ...
)
   from resultMsg_reportCard rm_rc
   inner join
   (
     select something
     from tbl_something
   ) a on rm_rc.something=a.something
   inner join
   (
     select something
     from tbl_somethingElse
   ) b on a.something=b.something
   inner join gg on a.something=gg.soemthing
   for xml path ('')
) x
inner join tbl_somethingElse se on x.something=es.something
```

first of all, I am sorry if my code is not clear enough because I do not have permission to use my company table names, so my only choice was to show main structure of a code

so, when I execute this code, I face **No column name was specified for column 1 of 'x'** error and also when I delete `for xml path('')` my query executed correctly!
I suppose I missed something easy and it is not a complicated error.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify not only table aliases but column aliases also

for example, this (APPLY) wont work

```
select t.size
, m.*
from (values (3)) as t(size)
outer apply (
    select fname
    from (values ('Mary', 1), ('John', 2), ('Sam', 3)) as t(fname, id)
    for xml path (''), type
) as m -- just table alias here
for xml path ('family')
```

and this (JOIN) wont work too

```
select t.size
, m.*
from (values (3)) as t(size)
join (
    select fname
    from (values ('Mary', 1), ('John', 2), ('Sam', 3)) as t(fname, id)
    for xml path (''), type
) as m on 1=1 -- just table alias here
for xml path ('family')
```

both will give you

> Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 18 No column name was specified for
>   column 1 of 'm'.

BUT specifying column aliases fixes both cases (JOIN, APPLY)

```
select t.size
, m.[members]
from (values (3)) as t(size)
join (
    select fname
    from (values ('Mary', 1), ('John', 2), ('Sam', 3)) as t(fname, id)
    for xml path (''), type
) as m([members]) on 1=1 -- here
for xml path ('family')
```

or

```
select t.size
, m.[members]
from (values (3)) as t(size)
outer apply (
    select fname
    from (values ('Mary', 1), ('John', 2), ('Sam', 3)) as t(fname, id)
    for xml path (''), type
) as m([members]) - here
for xml path ('family')
```

RESULT

```
<family>
  <size>3</size>
  <members>
    <fname>Mary</fname>
    <fname>John</fname>
    <fname>Sam</fname>
  </members>
</family>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the select query you should alias all the columns. For example.

```
select rm_rc.aa as [aa],rm_rc.bb as [bb]
```

Since you are considering x as a table and fetching the columns using an alias of a table.

Also consider forming xml finally like below.

```
inner join gg on a.something=gg.soemthing
) x
inner join tbl_somethingElse se on x.something=es.something
for xml path ('')
```

Comment: @dood In your question it doesn't seem that you have aliased.

Comment: yes of course. I meant I done that before and it does not response, when you comment your soloution, I do this again, it does not response again, unfortunately!

Comment: @dood isn't the for xml should come after the final inner join 'inner join tbl_somethingElse se on x.something=es.something' (after you form the table x)? I'm not able to get your scenario.

Comment: thanks for you suggest, but I do this now, and it does not response, error was: **The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.** 
in table x, I use a text, which should use in xml view, and I suppose for xml path should come at the end of x.

Comment: @dood Not clear about your requirement, If you just run the select (without insert) it will convert the columns into xml format. Not sure about your insert statement.

Comment: yes you are right, I deleted insert statement, and it does work correctly! but I need to use insert statement.
thanks for your help man.